# How to write validation rule with resource in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I use Laravel 8 with `Resource` to define routes in api.php and `DestroyProductRequest` in my controller:

```php
Route::resources([
    'product' => ProductController::class,
]);
```

In the controller:

```php
public function destroy(DestroyProductRequest $request, Product $product) {
    $product->delete();

    return Response::HTTP_OK;
}
```

In the DestroyProductRequest.php:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'id' => 'required|integer|exists:products,id',
    ];
}
```

Now the key is the `Route::resource` convert the incoming `id` from the url into a model. But now how can I write the correct rule in the the `rules()` function?

Now it sais `id: ["The id field is required."]` in the error response.

Any idea?

Comment: simply in the the api.php:
```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::resources([
    'product' => ProductController::class,
  ]);
```

Comment: From the browser I send a DELETE HTTP request to the `{{domain}}/api/product/1` url

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Laravel does not validate the route parameters.
You have add custom logic in order to work

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'product' => 'required|integer|exists:products,id',
    ];
}

protected function validationData()
{
    // Add the Route parameters to you data under validation
    return array_merge($this->all(),$this->route()->parameters());
}
```

In a normal use case, you wouldn't validate route request. Laravel would return a 404 Not Found exception. Which is a standard and appropriate response.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the resource, the route parameter is implicit biding key (product id), So Laravel bind the passed id as product implicitly. Change your Rules code segment as following,

```php
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'product' => 'required|integer|exists:products,id',
        ];
    }

    public function destroy(Product $product) {
        $product->delete();
    
        return Response::HTTP_OK;
    }
```

If you wanna add ACL

```php
     if ($user->can('destroy', $product)) {
            $product->delete();
        
            return Response::HTTP_OK;
        }
```

Comment: I tried this way, and the response is `product: ["The product field is required."]`

Comment: Moreover, You don't need to add validation when you are Using Route key binding Implicitly

Comment: public function destroy(Product $product) {
    $product->delete();

    return Response::HTTP_OK;
}

Comment: And how to define in this way the user has or has not access to this operation?

Comment: Using Middleware or Authorization Gates.

Comment: no way to organize the rule and `can` valdiation into `DestroyMenuItemRequest` file?

Comment: Do you wanna check User has permission or not?

Answer (score -2):

use `Validator` for your question

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function destroy(DestroyProductRequest $request, Product $product) {
    $rules = [
         'id' => 'required|integer|exists:products,id',
    ];
    $messages = [
        'id.required' => 'The id field is required.',
        'id.integer' => 'The id field need to be integer.',
        'id.exists' => 'The id field is exists.',
    ];
    Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages)->validate();
    $product->delete();
    return Response::HTTP_OK;
}
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation